# How weak are 64 bit hashs? Can I generate a hash of length X?

Tags: security, hash

I am working on an application where I need to hash binary data, and store the hash in a structure 64 bits long. I am looking for a cryptographic hash function. Ripemd-64 and elf-64 are some possibilities that I have found, but I can't find much data on them (e.g., have they been cracked with less than brute force matches, how long they would take to break, etc). Any links or details are most welcome.

I understand that 64 bits is going to somewhat insecure due to the length of hash. I may have some additional bits to play with (72-74). The problem is that I am not a cryptographer, so I have no idea how to modify a hash function to return some hash of length X. I figure that if I can use 72 bits over 64, I will gain a much bigger hash space. How do I change a hash function so that the length is some non-standard amount?

Any help is most welcome!

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: You can always calculate a longer hash with a well-known algorithm and only use as many bits as fits into your data structure. E.g. if you have 74 bits use half of sha-1 or 2/3 of ripemd-128.

Comment: I may end up going this direction if I can't find anything else, but it seems like there could be hidden problems.

Comment: The truncated output of a longer hash function is still good. The bits are evenly distributed, uncorrelated etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 64 bits isn't a whole lot for security purposes. It could be brute forced, depending on your application. But assuming you accept that fact and still want to move forward with it, I don't see any problem with just truncating a normal 128/256 bit hash.

Meaning, just use a strong hash function from any cryptographic library you want, and only use the first 64 bits of it. A "proper" method would be to find a hash algorithm natively outputting 64 bits, but as far as I know, people have pretty much stopped making them. It would be even harder to find an implementation available.

Having said that, I'd still urge you to look into making this data structure of yours larger.

Comment: I was thinking about that approach, but I am unsure if the output of a hash function like SHA is evenly random across all bits, or if some sections are better than others to use. Or even if it isn't any good without all bits.

Comment: Output of a good crypto hash function is statistically close to a random number, the more random the better. It's the whole 'crypto' point: you can't see any pattern on which to base your decoding effort. So you can get any bits from the hash value, e.g. middle bits, or a mix of non-adjacent bits — they're still good. The less bits, the easier a _brute force attack_ is, though.

Comment: @Erick: _as far as we know_, the SHA-2 functions (SHA-256, SHA-512) are evenly random across all bits. A small bias in parts of the output could still be compatible with the hash function resistance to collisions and preimages, so you are right to be cautious. However, no such bias is currently known. Therefore, truncating the hash function output to the length you wish is no problem per se -- at least, no more problematic than using a smaller output length: if you restrict the output to 64 bits, collisions are very easy and preimages are technologically feasible.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. For now, I'll go with the assumption that it is random. Sometimes you are forced into tradeoffs (like a 64-72 bit hash) and all you can do is find the best way forward. Thanks.